# Nested `if` statement not evaluating the result of an operation

Tags: ruby

I am generating a file in a temp directory.
If the file to be generated is different from an already existing file, then I wan't to update it, and run a command. If it's the same, then I can do nothing.

My code looks like this:

```
errstatus = 0
if FileUtils.identical?('/var/tmp/newfile', '/var/tmp/originalfile')
  $stderr.puts "Files are the same, nothing to do"
else
  $stderr.puts "Files are different, let's update them."

  if FileUtils.cp_r '/var/tmp/newfile', '/var/tmp/originalfile'
    $stderr.puts "File copied successfully."

    if system('systemcommand1 here')
      $stderr.puts "command ran OK"

      if system('systemcommand2 here')
        $stderr.puts "next command ran ok"

      else
        $stderr.puts "command 2 failed"
        errstatus = 1
      end
    else
      $stderr.puts "command 1 failed"
      errstatus = 1
    end
  end
end
```

When I run it when the files are different, I get the output:

```
Files are different, let's update them.
```

It runs with `FileUtils.cp_r` without any errors, but it doesn't tell that the File was copied successfully, or run the system command. I have used the same syntax to evaluate `FileUtils.identical?`, but it does not work for `FileUtils.cp_r`.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FileUtils::cp_r` returns `nil` (which in Ruby is falsy) if the copying was successful, raises an error if not. It will never return a truthy value, so making it a condition does not make sense.

Since it doesn't have an `else` statement right now, simply remove the `if` before it. If you want error handling for your `cp_r`, you will need to wrap it into a `begin..rescue` block.

Comment: Perfect, that helps a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because the `if FileUtils.cp_r '/var/tmp/newfile', '/var/tmp/originalfile'` doesn't have an `else` clause so if it returns `false` or throws and exception it doesn't enter the if.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This got me part of the way... as Marcin explained below, cp_r will return a nil if it works so this method of error checking was never going to work